# ElasticSearch - specifying an exact port (no port range)

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to specify an exact port for ElasticSearch to use for HTTP traffic. How can I do so? In the config file, it says it listens to a port range by default. How can I restrict this port range to just 1 port?

```
Elasticsearch, by default, binds itself to the 0.0.0.0 address, and listens
on port [9200-9300] for HTTP traffic and on port [9300-9400] for node-to-node
communication. (the range means that if the port is busy, it will automatically
try the next port).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In config folder.. There is an file called "elasticsearch.Yml". In that 
Parameters for port are commented..  Just remove hash before http.port and add port value to it..

```
    http.port : 5000
```

You can do this for both tcp and http